# SSIS For Each Loop Container/File System task

Tags: ssis

I have a File System task that will move a folder if a process job fails. The process job bulk inserts from a set of files. If one file fails the subsequent job to move the folder fails. I'm presuming that the process job is locking a file in the folder as I am getting and Access to path denied. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: What is a "process job"? You reference a subsequent job - is that a sql agent job or still part of SSIS? Perhaps a screen shot of your Control Flow and any other external processes might make your question a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving the folder contents as part of a single task I split the task into a copy and then deleted the directory contents. The problem has not reoccurred.